# Save config (jdbc-provider, jdbc-connection, mail) from Websphere (installed as Docker)

Tags: websphere

**Basis:**
I installed Websphere as Docker on Ubuntu and configured the JDBC settings manually.

**Question:**
How do I export this Websphere configuration to hand it over later when creating the Docker container?

I've tried many things, but haven't gotten anywhere yet

Comment: Docker is secondary here. I would like to know how to export configuration from Websphere. When building the container again, these configs should then be read in (like).

Comment: 1) if docker is secondary and does not influence the answer then don't tag with docker. 2) we are now definitely [off topic](/help/on-topic) as this is a server installation/configuration issue and not a question related to programming. There are other stackexchange site more appropriate. https://serverfault.com might be the good place (check site help section) else head to https://superuser.com. 3) when moving your question, you should consider developing the sentence `I've tried many things, but haven't gotten anywhere yet` as users there (as here) will probably ask for details.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [properties file-based configuration](https://www.ibm.com/docs/en/was/8.5.5?topic=wsadmin-using-properties-files-manage-system-configuration) as a way to save (export) and then later restore (import) a WebSphere configuration.

This works well when building Docker container images, and you'll see the [Websphere traditional Docker samples](https://github.com/WASdev/ci.docker.websphere-traditional/tree/main/samples/) using this technique.

As you noted, though, it can be used outside of Docker/container use cases as well.

There are several examples in the doc above including extracting cell properties:

```
AdminTask.extractConfigProperties('[-propertiesFileName 
 ConfigProperties_cell.props]')
```

and extracting server properties

```
AdminTask.extractConfigProperties('[-propertiesFileName ConfigProperties_server1.props
 -configData Server=server1]')
```

Note there is some tooling in the WebSphere traditional Docker project:
https://github.com/WASdev/ci.docker.websphere-traditional to make this type of function easier to use within a Docker build (e.g. you just place the properties file in a certain location instead of having to write and call the wsadmin command yourself), so it is worth reading through the doc.